# Is it possible to regard "vacant" and "vacancy" as allomorphs (variants) of the same root in Modern English?

Tags: linguistics, morphology

Am I right to consider /΄veikənt/ and /΄veikəns/ in those words as variants of one and the same root morpheme in Modern English. But it makes me hesitate in  my morphemic division if we take for analysis preside - presid-ent - presid-ency  (comp. also agent - agency, pregnant - pregnancy and also pirate - piracy, private - privacy, literate - literacy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the unit *vaca* could well be a morpheme in modern English.

Take the words *vacant*, *vacancy*, *vacation*, *evacuation*, *vacuum*, etc. They all have the *vaca/vacu* unit, which always pertains to emptiness in some way.

I think that since the words are related by emptiness, the original root is less important than how the morpheme is currently used in English.

It is, therefore, an allomorph since the morpheme varies phonologically, but its meaning remains the same.

Comment: So vacant and vacancy are allomorphs  of the same ME root morpheme, aren't they?

Comment: yes, the *vaca* of *vacancy* is IMO the same morpheme as the one in *vacancy*, but they are phonologically different.

Comment: If they were allomorphs of the same root morpheme, then the root morpheme should change without to change function.

Comment: @Kiamlaluno: which I believe they do

Answer (score 2):

I would say no; those words are not perceived as composed  from two morphemes, in English.

To talk of allomorphs, the words should be each composed by two morphemes, one of which is an allomorph and maintains the same function in both the words.
Supposing that the words are composed from *vacan-* as root, and *-t*/*-cy*, *vacan* cannot be the allomorph, as

- the pronunciation of *vacan* in both the words is the same (/ˈveɪkən/)
- *vacan* is written in the same way in both the words

*-t* and *-cy* cannot be allomorphs as the existing suffixes *-t* and *-cy* have two different functions.

Comment: As you know, French and Latin belong to the same language family. And many words of Romance origin were borrowed from French or directly from Latin. But this is all about etymological analysis, not morphological. According to the formal-semantic criteria these two words can be considered as those that contain the same root, the problem is whether the root is /veik/ (affixes -ant, -ancy, some scholars say they exist in ME) or /΄veikənt/ (if so then vacant and vacancy must be regarded as variants). No one will doubt the common root in pirate - piracy, why should we doubt it in vacant - vacancy?

Comment: EtymOnline says they're both from the same Latin.

Comment: @subic You asked about Modern English. In _vacancy_ and _vacant_ there aren't two morphemes that are allomorphs.